# Exception when connecting to Azure ServiceFabric from .NET Core 2.0 application

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, azure-service-fabric

I'm trying to connect to a secure Azure ServiceFabric cluster interactively from within a C# application using AAD as desribed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-connect-to-secure-cluster#connect-to-a-secure-cluster-interactively-using-azure-active-directory).  I'm running this from my local computer.

However, every time I run my console application I get the following exception when trying to call `GetClusterManifestAsync` (like in the example in the link above):

`Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Fabric.AzureActiveDirectory.Client, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies.
The system cannot find the file specified.
   at GetAccessToken(Char* authority, Char* audience, Char* client, Char* redirectUri, Boolean refreshSession, Char* outBuffer, Int32 outBufferSize)`

Obviously I must be missing some package or something is out of date on my computer but I cant seem to figure out what.

My .NET Core 2.0 application currently only references nuget package: "Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services (3.0.467)"

Comment: hitting this issue? https://github.com/Azure/service-fabric-issues/issues/218

Comment: I'm not using the ServiceFabricExplorer.exe, instead I'm writing my own application in C# to talk to SF.

Comment: You are probably missing the ADAL nuget package, but anyway ADAL does not support passing user & password in core, so you will need to use a different flow i.e. client credentials, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48666505/service-fabric-client-authentication-in-dotnetcore-userpasswordcredential-not-wo